# "R".match(%r[^R]) finds a match?

Tags: ruby

`"R".match(%r[^R])` finds a match.

I don't know much about regex but I thought `^` after a `[` negates the character class, the characters between the brackets.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your case brackets are not part of regex, your case is similar to `%r|^R|` or `%r'^R'` or place any character before `%` and after `R`
what you want is `%r|[^R]|` or `/[^R]/`

Comment: Or `%[[^R]]` (brackets used with `%` can be nested without causing problems).